# SQL array to string conversion error cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, mysql-error-1054

I am facing this weird problem here with file upload.
So when I upload the file everything goes fine. But when I don't select anyfile in upload and submit the form I get following error:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 749]

Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]

Query: INSERT INTO `masters` (`candidate_id`, `candidate_name`, `candidate_file_name`) VALUES ('heman', 'He Man', Array)
```

Now here is what I am doing: in my controller:

The function which makes call to file upload function:

```
            if ( $_FILES['data']['name']['Master'])
            {
                $this->upload_files();
            }
```

Here is the file upload function:

```
function upload_files() {

    $fcnt = 0;
    $vdata = $_FILES['data']['name']['Master'];
            echo "Vdata:";
            pr($vdata);
    foreach ( $vdata as $v ) 
    {
        $pro_files[] = array(
            'name'=>$_FILES['data']['name']['Master']['candidate_file_name'],
            'tmp'=>$_FILES['data']['tmp_name']['Master']['candidate_file_name'],
            'type'=>$_FILES['data']['type']['Master']['candidate_file_name'],

        );  
        echo "Pro_files:";
        pr($pro_files);
        $fcnt++;
    }

    $cnt = 0;

    $allowed = array(
        'xls','xlsx','db','mbd',
        'txt','pdf','doc','docx',
        'log','rtf','wpd','wps',
        'csv','dat','pps','ppt',
        'pptx','sdf','xml','bmp',
        'gif','jpg','png','psd',
        'thm','tif','svg','sql',
        'html','htm','js','php',
        'bin','mim','7z','deb',
        'gz','pkg','sit',
        'sitx','tar.gz','zip',
        'zipx','pdf'
    );

    foreach ( $pro_files as $file )
    {
        $fileType = $file['type'];
        $fileType2 = explode('/',$fileType);
        $fileName = $file['name'];
        $path = 'C:\wamp\www' . '\\' . $fileName;
        //if ( in_array($fileType2[1],$allowed)) 
        //{
        echo "fileName";    
        pr($fileName);
            if ( move_uploaded_file($file["tmp"], $path) )
            {
                $this->data['Master']['candidate_file_name'] = $fileName;
            }

        //}

        $cnt++;
    }

}
```

Here is how my debug data looks like:

```
  Array
  (
    [Master] => Array
        (
            [candidate_id] => heman
            [candidate_name] => He Man
            [candidate_file_name] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test.txt
                    [type] => text/plain
                    [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php329D.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 0
                )

        )

  )
```

Here is how vdata looks like:

```
Array
(
    [candidate_file_name] => 
)
```

here is how profiles looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [tmp] => 
            [type] => 
        )

)
```

filename comes out to be nothing.

here is how the pr($_FILES) looks like:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [Master] => Array
                        (
                            [candidate_file_name] => 
                        )

                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [Master] => Array
                        (
                            [candidate_file_name] => 
                        )

                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [Master] => Array
                        (
                            [candidate_file_name] => 
                        )

                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [Master] => Array
                        (
                            [candidate_file_name] => 4
                        )

                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [Master] => Array
                        (
                            [candidate_file_name] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am not able to figure out what the problem might be.
Can anyone help?
Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the name of the column to the form file name. But because the form field will come back as an array, the database doesn't know what to do with it. This is what you will need to do once you save the file into the location you put it:

```
$this->request->data['Master']['candidate_file_name'] = '/path/to/where/you/saved/the/file.ext';
```

If the form field was empty, then you just need to do:

```
unset($this->request->data['Master']['candidate_file_name']);
```

**UPDATE**

The best way to check this is:

```
if (empty($this->request->data['Master']['candidate_file_name']['name'])) {
   unset($this->request->data['Master']['candidate_file_name']);
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it can you please explain? I am a newbie to cakephp.

Comment: Look at your debug data in your post. `candidate_file_name` is coming back as an array of file information from the form (as it should). So if you do not modify that and just try to save it in the database, it is trying to save an array as a value. That is where the error is coming from. The database is expecting a string. So once you have uploaded the file and moved it to the directory you want it in, you need to update `candidate_file_name` to that location so when you SELECT it from the database later, it will point to the file in the correct location.

Comment: Hey I tried this but it seems to give the same error
    if (!empty($_FILES['data']['name']['Master']))
    {
     echo "hello";
     $this->upload_files();
     echo "hi";
    }
    
    else{
     unset($this->request->data['Master']['candidate_file_name']);
    }

Comment: You're checking the wrong thing. Check `if (empty($this->request->data['Master']['candidate_file_name']['name']))`. I think using the `$_FILES` var will just confuse you more. When using cake, use the cake variables.If you want to use $_FILES, then you need to use the complete check: `if (!empty($_FILES['data']['name']['Master']['candidate_file_name']))`.